# impute missing with interpolation by groups

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, missing-data, imputets

I am trying to impute missing value `NA` with interpolation by multiple groups.

I just subset a simple example:

```
Year    ST   CC   ID     MP     PS 
2002    15   3     3     NA    1.5
2003    15   3     3     NA    1.5
2004    15   3     3    193    1.5
2005    15   3     3    193    1.5
2006    15   3     3    348    1.5
2007    15   3     3    388    1.5
2008    15   3     3    388    1.5
1999    53   33    1     NA    3.4 
2000    53   33    1     NA    3.4        
2002    53   33    1     NA    2.9           
2003    53   33    1     NA    2.6           
2004    53   33    1     NA    2.6         
2005    53   33    1    170    3.8         
2006    53   33    1    170    3.0           
2007    53   33    1    330    4.2         
2008    53   33    1    330    5.0
```

I used `na.approx()` but got wrong. It seems that my data has missing value in the first observation within each group.

```
setDT(dt)[, MP_interpolate := na.approx(MP, na.rm = T), .(Year, ST, CC, ID)]

setDT(dt)[, MP_interpolate := if(length(na.omit(MP))<2) MP else na.approx(MP, na.rm=TRUE), .(Year, ST, CC, ID)]
```

I also tried package `imputeTS` but not work.

Both are incorrect. Does it mean using interpolation to impute missing is not a good idea?

I'm not sure which imputation way is better (Do not want to use `mean` or `median`). I'm thinking about using `PS` trend to impute `MP`. (Just my thought, not question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `imputeTS::na_kalman` in an `ave`. This also extrapolates, what you probably want.

```
library(imputeTS)

dt$MP.imp <- with(dt, ave(MP, ST, CC, ID, FUN=na_kalman))
#    Year ST CC ID  MP  PS   MP.imp
# 1  2001 15  3  3  NA 1.5 193.0000
# 2  2002 15  3  3  NA 1.5 193.0000
# 3  2003 15  3  3  NA 1.5 193.0000
# 4  2004 15  3  3 193 1.5 193.0000
# 5  2005 15  3  3 193 1.5 193.0000
# 6  2006 15  3  3 348 1.5 348.0000
# 7  2007 15  3  3 388 1.5 388.0000
# 8  2008 15  3  3 388 1.5 388.0000
# 9  1999 53 33  1  NA 3.4 170.2034
# 10 2000 53 33  1  NA 3.4 166.3867
# 11 2002 53 33  1  NA 2.9 164.4496
# 12 2003 53 33  1  NA 2.6 165.0018
# 13 2004 53 33  1  NA 2.6 168.6527
# 14 2005 53 33  1 170 3.8 170.0000
# 15 2006 53 33  1 170 3.0 170.0000
# 16 2007 53 33  1 330 4.2 330.0000
# 17 2008 53 33  1 330 5.0 330.0000
```

You probably want to include `year` in the `ave`, it wouldn't have worked otherwise in your sample data.

Comment: can you explain how `na_kalman` works. In `ID=1`, the `MP.imp` decreases and increases. It seems cool.

Comment: @PeterChen It's based on space state models proposed by [Kalman 1960](http://www.sontaglab.org/kalman4.pdf). The Kalman filter applies a smoothing algorithm based on a level, a trend, and a seasonal component to inter/extrapolate missings, and also handles nonstationary data. It is thus different from linear interpolation.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it based on another column to impute at first, like impute `MP` based on the trend of `PS`...

Comment: @PeterChen Actually it's just interpolating the grouped time series in an univariate manner. For multivariate interpolation you could make predictions, based e.g. on [`loess regression`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27796497/6574038). Or use multiple imputation like [`mice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) (parametric) or [`missForest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missForest/index.html) (non-parametric). But this leads to a rather statistical discussion, which is better suited to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `loess regression` helps a lot. Since there are lots of `NA` in the column, it seems that I need to research multivariate interpolation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have `NA` values at the beginning and end of the group, you should use `na.rm = FALSE` to get output of the same size as input. With `na.rm = TRUE`, the leading and trailing `NA`s are removed.

Also, you should not group by `year` because that would give you only one observation in a group.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)
dt[, MP_interpolate := as.integer(zoo::na.approx(MP, na.rm = FALSE)), .(ST, CC, ID)]
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(Year = c(2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 1999L, 2000L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L), ST = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L), CC = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), ID = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
MP = c(NA, NA, 193L, 193L, 348L, 388L, 388L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 170L, 170L, 330L, 330L), PS = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 2.6, 2.6, 3.8, 3, 4.2, 5)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: I got `NA` or `TRUE` in the new column.

Comment: It works for me though. I have also wrapped `as.integer` there so actually you should not be getting logical values. Can you check on the data which I have shared in the post?

Comment: Got warning message: `Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(setDT(dt), , `:=`(MP_interpolate, as.integer(na.approx(MP,  :
  Group 1 column 'MP_interpolate': 193 (type 'integer') at RHS position 3 taken as TRUE when assigning to type 'logical'
2: In `[.data.table`(setDT(dt), , `:=`(MP_interpolate, as.integer(na.approx(MP,  :
  Group 2 column 'MP_interpolate': 170 (type 'integer') at RHS position 6 taken as TRUE when assigning to type 'logical'`

Comment: Do you get this even on the data that I have shared? What is your `packageVersion('data.table')` ? I have `‘1.12.2’`.

Comment: `packageVersion('data.table'): ‘1.12.8’` and with your sample, I still got `NA` in the first observation within each group... `$ MP_interpolate: int  NA NA 193 193 348 388 388 NA NA NA ...`