# Transform dataset and summarize entries of column into a row of data

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains data in the following manner:

```
Name, Result, Date #A lot of other stuff as we, but these are the only relevant ones I think
Peter Parker, 150, 2018-03-03
Peter Parker, 155, 2018-03-04
Peter Parker, 156, 2018-03-05
Peter Parker, 154, 2018-03-06
Peter Parker, 158, 2018-03-07
Benny Thompson, 130, 2018-03-03
Benny Thompson, 132, 2018-03-04
Benny Thompson, 138, 2018-03-05
Benny Thompson, 140, 2018-03-07
Benny Thompson, 139, 2018-03-09
Mylo Thony, 177, 2018-03-11
```

some of the persons are present at least, lets say 5 times. I want to create a model to predict the 5th result with regression if I give it the first four. I therefore assume that all Persons are "behaving" equally and want to transform my data into this format:

```
150, 155, 156, 154, 158
130, 132, 138, 140, 139
```

and that only for all persons who at least have 5 results in the record. I have no idea where to start, I come from the Java and C++ department, usually I would just run a for loop over this, but this seems very un-R-like to me, at least I have never seen anything like this yet. What is the best approach to something like this?

Comment: Is the Date sequence identical for all Names?

Comment: No, it can vary greatly from the 1960's  until 2019

Comment: I see a few prior answers that might help here. Here's one using a kalman filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574665/impute-missing-with-interpolation-by-groups

Comment: This seems to indeed help once you get the data to the format where you have  the results in one row, but I am mostly having trouble to getting it there. I will however take a look at the kalman filter! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "row" format is not the best way to perform predictions on your data. I'll give an example with dplyr/tidyr for the data in one row case:

The data:

```
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Peter Parker", "Peter Parker", "Peter Parker", 
"Peter Parker", "Peter Parker", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", 
"Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Mylo Thony"
), Result = c(150L, 155L, 156L, 154L, 158L, 130L, 132L, 138L, 
140L, 139L, 177L), Date = c(" 2018-03-03", " 2018-03-04", " 2018-03-05", 
" 2018-03-06", " 2018-03-07", " 2018-03-03", " 2018-03-04", " 2018-03-05", 
" 2018-03-07", " 2018-03-09", " 2018-03-11"))

data
#>              Name Result        Date
#> 1    Peter Parker    150  2018-03-03
#> 2    Peter Parker    155  2018-03-04
#> 3    Peter Parker    156  2018-03-05
#> 4    Peter Parker    154  2018-03-06
#> 5    Peter Parker    158  2018-03-07
#> 6  Benny Thompson    130  2018-03-03
#> 7  Benny Thompson    132  2018-03-04
#> 8  Benny Thompson    138  2018-03-05
#> 9  Benny Thompson    140  2018-03-07
#> 10 Benny Thompson    139  2018-03-09
#> 11     Mylo Thony    177  2018-03-11
```

To filter and transforming the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_in_one_row <- data |> group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(count = n(), id = 1:n()) |>
  filter(count == 5)  |>   
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Name), names_from = id, 
              values_from = -c(Name, id))

data_in_one_row

#> # A tibble: 2 × 16
#> # Groups:   Name [2]
#>   Name       Resul…¹ Resul…² Resul…³ Resul…⁴ Resul…⁵ Date_1 Date_2 Date_3 Date_4
#>   <chr>        <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 Peter Par…     150     155     156     154     158 " 201… " 201… " 201… " 201…
#> 2 Benny Tho…     130     132     138     140     139 " 201… " 201… " 201… " 201…
#> # … with 6 more variables: Date_5 <chr>, count_1 <int>, count_2 <int>,
#> #   count_3 <int>, count_4 <int>, count_5 <int>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​Result_1, ²​Result_2, ³​Result_3, ⁴​Result_4, ⁵​Result_5
```

Eventually you can apply a single linear mode prediction, depending on your expectations (on the un transformed dataset).

```
data <- data |> group_by(Name) |> 
  mutate(count = n(), id = 1:n()) |>
  filter(count == 5) 

model <- lm(Result ~ Name + as.POSIXct(Date), data)

pred_dataset <- data |> group_by(Name) |> 
  summarise(Date = max(as.POSIXct(Date)) + 24 * 3600)

pred_dataset$prediction = predict(model, pred_dataset)

pred_dataset
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Name           Date                prediction
#>   <chr>          <dttm>                   <dbl>
#> 1 Benny Thompson 2018-03-10 00:00:00       143.
#> 2 Mylo Thony     2018-03-12 00:00:00       179.
#> 3 Peter Parker   2018-03-08 00:00:00       159.
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, the following steps have to be done:

- remove rows from participants with less than 5 observations
- transfer data to wide format

**Removing rows**

By using the `which` function from base R you can remove the participants with less than 5 observations.

```
x <- data.frame(Name=c("Peter Parker", "Peter Parker", "Peter Parker", "Peter Parker","Peter Parker", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Benny Thompson", "Mylo Thony"),
           Result=c(150,155, 156, 154, 158,130, 132, 138, 140, 139, 177))
x <- x[with(x, Name %in% names(which(table(Name)>=5))), ]
```

**Transfer to wide format**

Your data is currently in long format. It can be easily transfered to wide format using the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package.
The spread function requires a key column which contains the new column names.
If there are only 5 observations per person, you can just add a new column repeating the numbers 1 to 5 as often as there are unique values in your Name column (calculated with `n_distinct` from the `dplyr` package). Note that your data should be ordered by both Name and Date, so that the numbers are assigned to the correct observation.

```
 x$Measurement <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), dplyr::n_distinct(x$Name))
 x_wide <- tidyr::spread(x, Measurement, Result)
```

[image: output]

If you have more than 5 observations per person, the solution has to be modified.

Comment: Note that tidyr::spread was superseed by "pivot_wider".

Comment: This is also exactly what I needed, thanks for the quick reply, well deserved upvote. The other answer gave me some more tips on the evaluation, which might be helpful to future users, so I will accept it and "just" leave you with an upvote.